# Using @ExtraTypes annotation when subclass is private

Tags: gwt

I implemented a proxy client class for `Status` class from Twitter4J. I got the following error at runtime:

> The domain type twitter4j.internal.json.StatusJSONImpl cannot be sent
>   to the client

It's because I created a proxy for abstract class `Status` class and not for `StatusJSONImpl`. I saw that I should use @ExtraTypes annotation, but the class `StatusJSONImpl` is private and I can't reference it from outside the package. How can I solve this? Is it possible to turn on polymorphism not telling specific class?

Answer (score 1):

`@ExtraTypes` is for referencing proxy types that are not directly referenced by the graph of `RequestContext` methods and their argument and return types, recursively. E.g. a method returns `BaseProxy`, of which you have two sub-interfaces `FooProxy` and `BarProxy` that are never referenced anywhere. Without an `@ExtraTypes({ FooProxy.class, BarProxy.class })`, the RequestFactory generator wouldn't cross their path and thus wouldn't include them in the client-side deserialization code, so the method would never  possibly return an object implementing `FooProxy` or `BarProxy`.

In your case, it seems like you don't need `@ExtraTypes`, you just need a `Locator<Status,Void>` that will create a `StatusJSONImpl` object in its `create` method (you don't need to implement any other method if it's `ValueProxy`, just throw an exception or return null)